Where are Notepad temp/unsaved .txt files located?
Since Windows 11 (or maybe earlier) Windows Notepad internally stores unsaved files so if the application (or Windows) crashes they will be still there later. For example, Notepad++ stores those temp files in:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup

I've searched here (and searching online about this pointed me here too) :
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local

But it seems they are not there (I even grepped all .txt files in those directories recursively)

If I were to hazard a guess, despite it being bad practice, it probably is within the installation directory within WindowsApps which is a protected folder.

My guess would be \AppData\Local\Temp, but keep in mind they may not be .txt files. Word for instance when doing autosaves generates .tmp files, so if notepad is using a similar mechanism then it may also be using a similar naming scheme.

Found it in:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState

Not sure what is the encoding, at least Notepad++ couldn't identify it, but the text is there

there is a character every 2 bytes (l.i.k.e.t.h.i.s), but it's not UTF16

This was also helpful for me since I was migrating between PCs and I just copied the contents of both folders to be right where I left off.
